# Change image on mouseover in image slider

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am creating a module [Demo](http://www.sharkpixel.com/) something like that.i have create the image slider very well but not able to change the image on mousehover.

you can check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st1wodzq/) also.

```js
// You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
$(function() {

  // Slideshow 4
  $("#slider4").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    before: function() {
      $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
    },
    after: function() {
      $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.rslides {


  margin: 0 auto 40px;


}


#slider2,


#slider3 {


  box-shadow: none;


  -moz-box-shadow: none;


  -webkit-box-shadow: none;


  margin: 0 auto;


}


.rslides_tabs {


  list-style: none;


  padding: 0;


  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);


  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);


  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);


  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);


  font-size: 18px;


  list-style: none;


  margin: 0 auto 50px;


  max-width: 540px;


  padding: 10px 0;


  text-align: center;


  width: 100%;


}


.rslides_tabs li {


  display: inline;


  float: none;


  margin-right: 1px;


}


.rslides_tabs a {


  width: auto;


  line-height: 20px;


  padding: 9px 20px;


  height: auto;


  background: transparent;


  display: inline;


}


.rslides_tabs li:first-child {


  margin-left: 0;


}


.rslides_tabs .rslides_here a {


  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);


  color: #fff;


  font-weight: bold;


}


a {


  color: #fff;


  text-decoration: none;


}


#download {


  background: #333;


  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);


  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);


  border-radius: 5px;


  -moz-border-radius: 5px;


  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


  display: block;


  font-size: 20px;


  font-weight: bold;


  margin: 60px auto;


  max-width: 500px;


  padding: 20px;


}


#download:hover {


  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);


}


.footer {


  font-size: 11px;


}


/* Callback example */


h3 {


  font: 20px/30px"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;


  text-align: center;


  color: #fff;


}


.events {


  list-style: none;


}


.callbacks_container {


  margin-bottom: 50px;


  position: relative;


  float: left;


  width: 100%;


}


.callbacks {


  position: relative;


  list-style: none;


  overflow: hidden;


  width: 100%;


  padding: 0;


  margin: 0;


}


.callbacks ul {


  text-align: center;


  margin-left: auto;


  margin-right: auto


}


.callbacks li {


  position: absolute;


  width: 100%;


  left: 0;


  top: 0;


  display: inline-block;


  

}


.callbacks img {  


  display: block;


  position: relative;


  z-index: 1;


  height: auto;


  border: 0;
  width:100%;


}


.callbacks .caption {


  display: block;


  position: absolute;


  z-index: 2;


  font-size: 20px;


  text-shadow: none;


  color: #fff;


  background: #000;


  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);


  left: 0;


  right: 0;


  bottom: 0;


  padding: 10px 20px;


  margin: 0;


  max-width: none;


}


.callbacks_nav {


  position: absolute;


  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);


  top: 52%;


  left: 0;


  opacity: 0.7;


  z-index: 3;


  text-indent: -9999px;


  overflow: hidden;


  text-decoration: none;


  height: 61px;


  width: 38px;


  background: transparent url("https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/blob/master/demo/themes/themes.gif") no-repeat left top;


  margin-top: -45px;


}


.callbacks_nav:active {


  opacity: 1.0;


}


.callbacks_nav.next {


  left: auto;


  background-position: right top;


  right: 0;


}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {


  h1 {


    font: 24px/50px"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;


  }


  .callbacks_nav {


    top: 47%;


  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<div class="callbacks_container">
  <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
    <li>
      <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/1.jpg" alt="">

    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/2.jpg" alt="">

    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/3.jpg" alt="">

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

every image have 2 parts.first is before and 2nd is after.the only thing which i am not able to create is changing the 2nd image on mousehover.Or suggest any other way to achieve this.

please help me to create this.

Comment: so you need to change the image on hover ?

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath yes dear

Comment: can you make a fiddle ??

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath i have tried but not able to create fiddle While i was doing the same thing which i used to create snippit.

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath ok i am waiting for your valuable response.

Comment: this is the fiddle i made http://jsfiddle.net/st1wodzq/

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath but in hover image is not changing

Comment: i just made fiddle of your question only

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath ohh ohk got it

Comment: i have added an answer..which you can follow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67084/discussion-between-sajad-karuthedath-and-gitz).

Answer (score 3):

If you check the source of the demo site you will find SEOGallery with urls for normal and hover states.

```
 var SEOGallery = {
                fullSrcs : ["http:\/\/www.sharkpixel.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/Beauty_Retouch_40.jpg",...], 
                srcs : ["http:\/\/www.sharkpixel.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/Beauty_Retouch_40-1066x700.jpg",....], 
            };
```

And in [Gallery.js](http://www.sharkpixel.com/wp-content/themes/kristi/js/gallery.js?ver=3.8.5) the logic is present where it fetches the srcs from the SEOGallery and toggles on mouseneter and mouseleave. The variables imgPars etc are defined on top.

```
imgPars.on('mouseenter', '.after', function() {
        var img = $(this);
        img.replaceWith(hoverImgs.filter('[src="' + 
            hoverSrc(img.attr('src')) + '"]'));
    });

    imgPars.on('mouseleave', '.before', function() {
        var img = $(this);
        img.replaceWith(imgs.filter('[src="' + 
            origSrc(img.attr('src')) + '"]'));
    });
```

Update:

I have used the same code over there and changed few things like creating the li than a div for the `ul.rslides`.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/st1wodzq/1/)

Comment: please provide a demo..!! Lfc fan here too..!! YNWA

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath added a fiddle...hehe..YNWA :)

Comment: @anpsmn i have attach it to my code and working fine. but getting the align problem with the navigation buttons next and previous. how can i use image Instead the link of next and previous.

Comment: @Gitz Add the rslides css. It will style the navs correctly.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the below script if you have exactly the same name with before and after images then use

```
$(function() {

  // Slideshow 4
  $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    before: function() {
      alert('before');

    },
    after: function() {
      alert('after');
    }
  });

 //added this snippet
    $( "img" ).hover(function(){
     alert('img');
        $(this).attr( "src", "img-after" );

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` on very image. something like

```
 <div class="callbacks_container">
  <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
    <li>
      <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src = 'http://responsiveslides.com/1-after.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src = 'http://responsiveslides.com/1.jpg';" alt="">

    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/2.jpg" onmouseover="this.src = 'http://responsiveslides.com/2-after.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src = 'http://responsiveslides.com/2.jpg';" alt="">

    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://responsiveslides.com/3.jpg" onmouseover="this.src = 'http://responsiveslides.com/3-after.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src = 'http://responsiveslides.com/3.jpg';" alt="">

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is too short :O.that is what i am looking for :)